# Cannot link the header file using gcc linker in windows

Tags: c++, c, gcc, hyperlink, g++

hello.c will use the header file plugin.h. If I want to use gcc to compile, can I know how should I write the -LXXX.
gcc -o hello hello.c -LXXX

Currently my project structure look like this
project directory is (C:\project)
project

- examples/ hello.c
- include / plugins/ plugin.h

Comment: The `-L` option is for **libraries**, use the `-I` for header files. Probably `-I../include/plugins`

Comment: You never link header files, you compile (by using `#include`) them. Linking is for object files and libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You don't link the header file, you include it. You link object files and static/shared libraries, which are already compiled files.

But to answer your question, you *include* your plugin with the `-I` option.

```bash
g++ -O2 examples/hello.c -I include/plugins -o hello
```

Or if you have a library to link say in `lib`:

```bash
g++ -O2 examples/hello.c -I include/plugins -L lib/plugins -lplugin -o hello
```

Or if you want to do in two steps (notice the `-c`)

```bash
g++ -O2 -c examples/hello.c -I include/plugins -o hello.o
g++ hello.o -L lib/plugins -lplugin -o hello
```

Comment: so in my hello.c I should write #include <plugins/plugin.h> or #include <plugin.h> ?

Comment: If it is in your sources you should use double quotes. 
If you are passing the full path with `-Iinclude/plugins` then you should do just `#include "plugin.h"`. 
If you are passing just `-Iinclude` then you should do `#include "plugins/plugin.h"`.

Comment: @Tim You don;t need to mention plugins twice, either mention it in `-I` or mention it in `#include` not both.

Comment: Can you tell me what those options do `-L lib/plugins -lplugin` ?

Comment: These are the location and (short) name of the libraries to link against.  For example, if a third party library is located at `/usr/lib/libboost_system.so` then you would pass `-L/usr/lib -lboost_system` to the linker arguments.